# Changing prefab start color during playtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

due to a day/night cycle in my game I need to change the color of a smoke prefab during playtime according the game time but I am having an hard time figuring how to change it several times.

My script works fine to instantiate the prefab with the start color that I want but I am not being able to change it again afterwards.

This is my code:

```
class Smoke1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject myPrefab;
    public  static GameObject newSmoke;
    public GameObject canvasObject;

void Start()
        {
        GameObject newSmoke = Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(397, -394, 90), Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
        newSmoke.transform.SetParent(canvasObject.transform, false);
        newSmoke.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

        newSmoke.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().startColor = Color.red;           
        }

    void Update()
        {
        if (TimeManager.gametimeDecimal < 6.0m)       
            newSmoke.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().startColor = Color.blue;

        if (TimeManager.gametimeDecimal >= 6.0m && TimeManager.gametimeDecimal <= 8.0m)
            newSmoke.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().startColor = Color.yellow;

        if (TimeManager.gametimeDecimal > 8.0m && TimeManager.gametimeDecimal < 19.0m)
            newSmoke.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().startColor = Color.green;
        }
```

And this is my hierarchy:[image]

When I change the start color manually trough the inspector during playtime it works, but I can't figure on how to make my script do it.

Can you give me any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the value returned by `TimeManager.gametimeDecimal` ? (using Debug.Log)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the 'newSmoke' variable again in your Start Method so when you instantiate an object it's not getting into the static variable but a local variable called the same.

So the first line of your Start should be changed to this :

```
newSmoke = Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(397, -394, 90), Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
```